# How to remove black outline from Seurat's VlnPlot violin plot

Tags: seurat, ggplot2

Using Seurat's VlnPlot, how can I remove the black outline around the violin plot?

For example, how can I change from the following graph with a (black) outline:

```r
    VlnPlot(ilc2,
        features = "gene",
        split.by = "group", 
        cols = c("#198BFD", "#EC6464"),
        pt.size = 0) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

To a graph like the one below, which does not have an outline around the violin plot:

[image]

Comment: Please consider "accepting" your answer and upvoting the other helpful answer here.

Answer (score 2):

wish there was a more subtle answer, but this works.  Place this previous to your VlnPlot

```r
update_geom_defaults("violin", aes(linewidth = 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
vln_df = data.frame(gene = ilc2_bs[["RNA"]]@data[ "gene", ],
                    group = ilc2$group)

ggplot(vln_df, aes(x = group, 
                   y = gene, fill = group)) + 
  geom_violin(aes(fill = group, 
                  color = gene),
              color = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#619CFF", "#F8766D")) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = group),
               width = 0.1) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```